# Retrieve S3 bucket settings with Python

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto3

I have a requirement to record hundreds of S3 buckets for the settings on the Properties tab for each bucket.  This is to verify that none are public, none are unencrypted.  Later I will have to provide the ACL for each bucket as well.

the following is as far as I have gotten

```
from boto3.session import Session
import config
import pandas as pd

ACCESS_KEY=config.awsAccessKey
SECRET_KEY=config.awsSecretKey

session = Session(aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
                  aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY)
s3 = session.resource('s3')

counter = 0
csv_list = []
path = '//ant.amazon.com/dept/DCGSI/Extracts/s3_buckets_list.csv'

for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
    for obj in bucket.objects.all():
        if counter == 10:
            break
        bucketsTwoDeep = bucket.name + obj.key
        counter += 1
```

This gives me the bucket and the first level "folder" object.  I can't seem to find a way to get the properties on the bucket.  Is there a way?  Once I can get the data I will have to put it into a CSV or something, so hopefully anything that I can get will be dataframeable.

Answer (score 0):

There are a whole stack of get_bucket methods in the s3client that might be what you're looking for.  get_bucket_encryption() and get_bucket_acl() spring to mind.

e.g.

```
Python 3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48eceb, Dec 19 2017, 06:04:45) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import boto3
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> s3client = boto3.client('s3')
>>> response = s3client.get_bucket_acl(Bucket = 'bucketname')
>>> pprint (response['Grants'])
[{'Grantee': {'DisplayName': 'username',
              'ID': '3c9b78c1dbb3599d60dab12c5d9c9d7eef13ca95e2505d6e022c98345c70e5fc',
              'Type': 'CanonicalUser'},
  'Permission': 'FULL_CONTROL'}]
```

Full list of s3 Client commands at https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#client

Comment: oh client instead of resource.  Let me look into that.